# AES 256 bit key to plaintext conversion?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, key-management, aes

I'm a little rusty on cryptography, but I have successfully acquired a 256 bit key that is used for encryption and I want to know if it is possible to reverse it into its corresponding plain text password. If yes, how do I do that?

Comment: You mean a 256-bit hash? AES keys are used to encrypt data.  So you would need to use the key to decrypt the password blob; if it is in fact an AES key.

Comment: Yes, I guess it's a 256 bit hash corresponding to the AES key that I located in memory. If it's a hash, it cannot be reversed right?

Comment: Fairly unlikely

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a meaningful question.

An AES key is simply a sequence of 256 bits.  Some uses of AES (eg. file encryption) compute their key from a password through the use of a [key derivation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) (KDF), but most (such as SSL and most disk encryption) simply generate a block of random data and use that as the key.

Even if the implementation you're working with is one that runs a password through a KDF, reversing it is not practical: virtually every KDF uses a [cryptographic hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), and reversing it means performing a [preimage attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack) -- something every cryptographic hash function is supposed to be resistant to.